# How to prevent wildcard to be interpreted in exec()?

Tags: php, sql, shell, wildcard

I want to print my SQL statement, to a debug file :

```
$dbh = new PDO( "mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name" , $db_user, $db_password );
$sql = "SELECT * from $db_table";

// do somethings ... 

// Print SQL statement to file for debugging
exec( " echo DEBUG: $sql > /tmp/sql.debug " );

$statement = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
```

But the wildcard will be interpret as file lists in working directory, so I got the result liks this

```
$ cat /tmp/sql.debug   
SELECT **1.php 2.php 3.php** from syslog WHERE program = xxx AND ip = 192.168.1.1
```

How can I prevent the wildcard to be interpreted in exec(), to get correct debug message ?

Comment: The shell accepts backslash as an escape charachter.  You'd have to escape the backslash again in PHP, so try: `select \\* from $db_table`

Comment: Escape the backslash again will get correct debug message, but PDO query will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `exec` to invoke `echo` command.

PHP native function **[error_log](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)** could achieve your requirement.

```
error_log($sql, 3, '/tmp/sql.debug');
```

The fix for your code is to quote your sql string for echoing.

```
exec( " echo 'DEBUG: $sql' > /tmp/sql.debug " );
```